# Add index key to multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can i add key index for a multidimensional array.

The array is fetched from from file gets contens url.

The variable that holds the array is looking like this:

`$data = array(array($number, $firstmane, $lastname, $street));`

The output is looking like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13564
            [1] => Bill
            [2] => Willson
            [3] => St 4546
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13295
            [1] => Ken
            [2] => Jibs
            [3] =>  St 4156
        )

)
```

How can i add index key so the array will look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13564
            [1] => Bill
            [2] => Willson
            [3] => St 4546
        )

)
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13295
            [1] => Ken
            [2] => Jibs
            [3] =>  St 4156
        )

)
```

UPDATE

More Complete Code

```
foreach ($json_obj['items'] as $order) { 
    $ordrenr = $order['id']; 
    $fornavn= $order['billingPerson']['firstName']; 
    $etternavn= $order['billingPerson']['lastName']; 
    $adresse = $order['billingPerson']['street']; 
    $header = ['ID' => 'string', 
                'Firstname' => 'string', 
                'Lastname' => 'string', 
                'street' => 'string' 
            ]; 
    $rader = array(array($ordrenr, $fornavn, $etternavn, $adresse)); 
    print_r( $rader ); 
    $writer = new XLSXWriter(); 
    $writer->setAuthor('USERNAME'); 
    $writer->writeSheet($rader, 'RESULT', $header); 
    $writer->writeToFile("/media/files/filename.xlsx" ); 
}
```

Comment: I assume you are doing this in a loop? So `$data[] = array($number, $firstname, $lastname, $street);`

Comment: yes by foreach the items as $

Comment: Then for reference, if you show us more of the actual code we can be sure we are giving a useful and relevant answer, rather than having to make assumptions. Also questions that are unclear are of little use to other that may be searching for answers to their problems that may be similiar to yours

Comment: strugling a bit to add more code by edit the post

Comment: foreach ($json_obj['items'] as $order) {
$ordrenr =  $order['id'];
$fornavn= $order['billingPerson']['firstName'];
$etternavn= $order['billingPerson']['lastName'];
$adresse = $order['billingPerson']['street'];
 
$header = ['ID' => 'string',
'Firstname' => 'string',
'Lastname' => 'string',
'street' => 'string' ];
$rader = array(array($ordrenr, $fornavn, $etternavn, $adresse));
print_r( $rader );

$writer = new XLSXWriter();
$writer->setAuthor('USERNAME');
$writer->writeSheet($rader, 'RESULT', $header);
$writer->writeToFile("/media/files/filename.xlsx"  );
  }

Comment: **Again** use the edit button under the question [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71734964/edit) to add requested information ot your question

Comment: Now its readable

Answer (score 0):

You are just assigning an array of the array to $data.
so you will only get the last array value in $data.

Try with following code in loop.
$data[] = array($number, $firstmane, $lastname, $street);

$a= array('13564','Bill','Willson','St 4546');
$b= array('13295','Ken','Jibs','St 4546');

$data[] = array($a);

$data[] = array($b);

print_r($data);

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array item using `$arr[] = [1,2,3];` and also I have changed the loop to create the complete array before attempting to write it out to the spreadsheet.

```
foreach ($json_obj['items'] as $order) { 
    $ordrenr = $order['id']; 
    $fornavn= $order['billingPerson']['firstName']; 
    $etternavn= $order['billingPerson']['lastName']; 
    $adresse = $order['billingPerson']['street']; 
    $header = ['ID' => 'string', 
                'Firstname' => 'string', 
                'Lastname' => 'string', 
                'street' => 'string' 
            ]; 
    //$rader = array(array($ordrenr, $fornavn, $etternavn, $adresse)); 

    $rader[] = [$ordrenr, $fornavn, $etternavn, $adresse]; 
}

print_r( $rader ); 
$writer = new XLSXWriter(); 
$writer->setAuthor('USERNAME'); 
$writer->writeSheet($rader, 'RESULT', $header); 
$writer->writeToFile("/media/files/filename.xlsx" );
```